# How to append bot's reply into web-chat?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am unable to get the response from the bot and append it to the web-chat provided by the MS Botframework.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Created a bot on https://dev.botframework.com/ (without migration)
2. Integrated Web Chat and Direct Line
3. Created a **flask listener server** and generated HTTPS using **ngrok**
4. Gave created server's address as messaging endpoint for the bot

[image]

5. Generated a HTML page using below code (running locally without any server)

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="bot"/>
>     <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
>     <script>
>       BotChat.App({
>         directLine: { secret: 'direct_line_secret_key' },
>         user: { id: 'userid' },
>         bot: { id: 'botid' },
>         resize: 'detect'
>       }, document.getElementById("bot"));
>     </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Now I am able to send message from the UI as user, and able to capture it in the flask listener server.
**But how do I reply from the server so that message will come from bot and append to the UI?**

Am I missing something?

I have tried https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{convoId}/activities to POST a request but that again comes back to server only and does not append to web-chat.

`data = json.dumps({"type": "message","from":{"id":"botid"},"text": "Hii!"})`

```
requests.post('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/' + r['conversation']['id'] + '/activities', 
headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + "secret_key", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": "512"},data=data
```

**NOTE:** I am using botframework only for the web-chat UI and nothing else.

**EDIT 1:**

> ## sent this from web-chat ui
>
> http://bcebb07a.ngrok.io/webhook' [POST]>
>   ************************************************************************** {'type': 'message', 'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000002',
>   'timestamp': '2018-06-05T06:51:45.3174659Z', 'serviceUrl':
>   'https://directline.botframework.com/', 'channelId': 'directline',
>   'from': {'id': 'sid'}, 'conversation': {'id':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY'}, 'recipient': {'id':
>   'one_assist@CrbpWod1mw8', 'name': 'OneAssist'}, 'textFormat': 'plain',
>   'locale': 'en-US', **'text': 'hello how are you'**, 'channelData':
>   {'clientActivityId': '1528180308547.7414264322396316.5'}}
>   5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY
>
> ####################################################################  {'messages': [{'id':
>
> '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000000', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:32:50.9651813Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.0'}, 'images': [], 'attachments': []},
>   {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000001', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:47:14.1602925Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'how are you', 'channelData':
>   {'clientActivityId': '1528180308547.7414264322396316.3'}, 'images':
>   [], 'attachments': []}, {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000002',
>   'conversationId': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created':
>   '2018-06-05T06:51:45.3174659Z', 'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello how are
>   you', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.5'}, 'images': [], 'attachments':
>   []}], 'watermark': '2'}
>
> {   "error": {
>       "code": "BotError",
>       "message": "Failed to send activity: bot timed out"   },   "httpStatusCode": 504 }
>   127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2018 12:22:12] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   ************************************************************************** http://bcebb07a.ngrok.io/webhook' [POST]>
>   ************************************************************************** {'type': 'conversationUpdate', 'id': 'D3XJ6CAaVsc', 'timestamp':
>   '2018-06-05T06:51:56.7508828Z', 'serviceUrl':
>   'https://directline.botframework.com/', 'channelId': 'directline',
>   'from': {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY'}, 'conversation': {'id':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY'}, 'recipient': {'id':
>   'one_assist@CrbpWod1mw8', 'name': 'OneAssist'}, 'membersAdded':
>   [{'id': 'botid'}]} 5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY
>
> ####################################################################  {'messages': [{'id':
>
> '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000000', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:32:50.9651813Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.0'}, 'images': [], 'attachments': []},
>   {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000001', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:47:14.1602925Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'how are you', 'channelData':
>   {'clientActivityId': '1528180308547.7414264322396316.3'}, 'images':
>   [], 'attachments': []}, {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000002',
>   'conversationId': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created':
>   '2018-06-05T06:51:45.3174659Z', 'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello how are
>   you', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.5'}, 'images': [], 'attachments':
>   []}], 'watermark': '2'}
>
> {   "error": {
>       "code": "BotError",
>       "message": "Failed to send activity: bot timed out"   },   "httpStatusCode": 504 }
>   127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2018 12:22:32] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> **# sent this from the server code**
>   ************************************************************************** http://bcebb07a.ngrok.io/webhook' [POST]>
>   ************************************************************************** {'type': 'message', 'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000003',
>   'timestamp': '2018-06-05T06:52:16.6925987Z', 'serviceUrl':
>   'https://directline.botframework.com/', 'channelId': 'directline',
>   'from': {'id': 'botid'}, 'conversation': {'id':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY'}, 'recipient': {'id':
>   'one_assist@CrbpWod1mw8', 'name': 'OneAssist'}, **'text': 'Hii!'**}
>   5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY
>
> ####################################################################  {'messages': [{'id':
>
> '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000000', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:32:50.9651813Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.0'}, 'images': [], 'attachments': []},
>   {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000001', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:47:14.1602925Z',
>   'from': 'sid', 'text': 'how are you', 'channelData':
>   {'clientActivityId': '1528180308547.7414264322396316.3'}, 'images':
>   [], 'attachments': []}, {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000002',
>   'conversationId': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created':
>   '2018-06-05T06:51:45.3174659Z', 'from': 'sid', 'text': 'hello how are
>   you', 'channelData': {'clientActivityId':
>   '1528180308547.7414264322396316.5'}, 'images': [], 'attachments': []},
>   {'id': '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY|0000003', 'conversationId':
>   '5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY', 'created': '2018-06-05T06:52:16.6925987Z',
>   'from': 'botid', 'text': 'Hii!', 'images': [], 'attachments': []}],
>   'watermark': '3'}
>   https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY/activities/
>
> https://directline.botframework.com/v3/conversations/5DvIa5ImiPF4G6WnGlPYyY/activities
>    {   "error": {
>       "code": "BotError",
>       "message": "Failed to send activity: bot timed out"   },   "httpStatusCode": 504 }

Comment: Is your bot working fine in the Test in Web Chat option in the Azure portal ?

Comment: @AnitaGeorge no, i was able to get message at backend but not able to send it back to UI

Comment: What does the activity you are sending to webchat look like?

Comment: Do you have a repo for your implementation of the bot framework? 

The webchat itself communicates with the bot via a Get polling request or a stream that is opened when a chat window is created. More info on that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). Implementing one of these endpoints should help towards solving this issue. But it would be easier to answer with more information on your bot.

Comment: @JasonSowers `data = json.dumps({"type": "message","from":{"id":"botid"},"text": "Hii!"})`. updated in the question as well

Comment: @MarkB sorry i dont have any repo. i have created bot on dev.botframework.com without any **azure subscription**. I have not created any bot service on azure portal as I am not using anything other than web-chat.
i have created my own server for message end-point, and i am receiving messages on server. only problem is i dont know how to send message from that server/bot back to web-chat UI.

Comment: @MarkB i have updated question details with logs as well. do help please.

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible for your version of your bot to show us? It is unclear what the structure of your project is from the currently available information. It's possible that you might need to create a free tier subscription for Azure to access the functionality you are trying to use.

Comment: that's what i suspect, but since i am only using web-chat along with direct-line it should not be needed. hence the confusion. @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using ngrok and I notice in your logs there are references to 127.0.0.1.  Try adding the -host-header parameter to your ngrok command line.

For example I use

```
ngrok http -host-header=localhost:55486 55486
```

Where 55486 is the port number my endpoint sits on.

Comment: no luck.. still same error. i was already able to receive messages on endpoint btw.